# how to add an offset to and offset

Tags: c#, winforms, byte, offset

Hypothetically speaking I have a process located at 0x92000000 in my memory. When I dump that process and view inside of it and find another offset that is let's say 0x121212. How would I add those together to get the actual offset which would be 0x92121212?

I have tried plenty of things I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to find anything on this subject. Any help will be awesome!

Comment: Are you looking for anything specific? Just being curious or trying to debug some issue happening in native code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't say this for sure without knowing how the offset is interpreted, i.e. how the jump is performed (which instruction is used). The jump might be relative ("skip the next 50 instructions") or absolute ("continue at address x").